# Git rebase said I modified 380 files when I only touched 5

Tags: git, rebase

I rebased using the commands listed below. The result was git started saying that I had modified 380 different files when my commits only touched 5.

From my branch:

```
git rebase main

git push

git pull
[it says "Rebasing.." and counts to 59]
git push
[git claims I have changes in 380 different files when I only modified 5]
```

What happened? Why did git start saying I modified 380 files when I only touched 5 of them? How can I rebase without this type of thing happening?

Comment: It's 5 files because that's what you think you modified? Or it's only 5 files if you run a diff against the branch, for example? What I think might be going on is that there is an EOL format change in the files that you might not be aware of.

Comment: Is this normal/expected when rebasing?

Comment: Normally? Nope. But If there was an EOL-format change? Sure.... if you take a look at the revisions that you _think_ only have 5 files modified, it will contain a few more (actually, it can be quite a lot more than a few) modified files. But it's just a theory at this moment.